# It was not possible to parse your key when trying to test Oauth in postman

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

I was working on Oauth passport laravel. It was working fine on my previous computer, but I had to switch machines. My new machine has PHP 8, my Laravel project is of 7.30.0 version, and my lcobucci/jwt version is 3.3.3. When I try to hit register route on postman I get the following error message.

```
InvalidArgumentException: It was not possible to parse your key, reason:  in file
C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\OpenSSL.php
on line 90

    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\OpenSSL.php(47):
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL-&gt;validateKey(Object(OpenSSLAsymmetricKey))
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\OpenSSL.php(21):
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL-&gt;getPrivateKey('-----BEGIN RSA ...',
NULL)
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\BaseSigner.php(36):
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\OpenSSL-&gt;createHash('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...',
Object(Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key))
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Builder.php(470):
Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\BaseSigner-&gt;sign('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...',
Object(Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key))
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Builder.php(450):
Lcobucci\JWT\Builder-&gt;createSignature(Array,
Object(Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256),
Object(Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key))
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Entities\Traits\AccessTokenTrait.php(41):
Lcobucci\JWT\Builder-&gt;getToken()
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\ResponseTypes\BearerTokenResponse.php(28):
Laravel\Passport\Bridge\AccessToken-&gt;convertToJWT(Object(League\OAuth2\Server\CryptKey))
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\AuthorizationServer.php(202):
League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\BearerTokenResponse-&gt;generateHttpResponse(Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php(114):
League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer-&gt;respondToAccessTokenRequest(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest),
Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
    #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\passport\src\PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php(71):
Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenFactory-&gt;dispatchRequestToAuthorizationServer(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest))
    #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\passport\src\HasApiTokens.php(67):
Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenFactory-&gt;make(32, 'MyApp',
Array)
    #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\app\Http\Controllers\API\CCVTController.php(48):
App\CCVTPassport-&gt;createToken('MyApp')
    #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54):
App\Http\Controllers\API\CCVTController-&gt;register(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php(45):
Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction('register', Array)
    #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(239):
Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
Object(App\Http\Controllers\API\CCVTController), 'register')
    #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php(196):
Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController()
    #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(685):
Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run()
    #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128):
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(41):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php(59):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure), 60, '1')
    #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(687):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
    #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(662):
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(628):
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
    #26 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(617):
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #27 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(165):
Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #28 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(128):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #29 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #30 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #31 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #32 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #33 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #34 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #35 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #36 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #37 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors\src\HandleCors.php(37):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #38 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #39 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\fideloper\proxy\src\TrustProxies.php(57):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #40 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(167):
Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request),
Object(Closure))
    #41 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #42 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(140):
Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then(Object(Closure))
    #43 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(109):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #44 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\public\index.php(55):
Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #45 C:\xampp\htdocs\ccvtlicensing\ccvt-licensing\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
    #46 {main}
```

I have tried downgrading and upgrading lcobucci/jwt, and also have ran
`php artisan passport:install` and `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: how are you parsing it ?

Comment: I am testing register in passport Oauth on postman
currently i am passing these fields
name 
email
password
c_password

Comment: I downgraded php from 8 version to 7.4.2 now it is working fine

Answer (score 4):

By downgrading from php version 8 to version 7.4 solved my issue